# How to fix BCryptDecrypt returing 0xC000003E (STATUS_DATA_ERROR)?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to develop a dll in C++ that performs DES enc/dec using Bcrypt.h.
`BCryptEncrypt()` is working fine for me but `BCryptDecrypt()` is causing issues at certain times.

for example for single DES decryption if I use '4064DAD9640DA11A' as 8 byte DES key component, BCryptDecrypt() correctly decrypts an 16 byte cipher text and returns 8 byte of plain text.
however if I use 'CB54F4E5F1947CAD' as 8 byte DES key component, `BCryptDecrypt()` returns error_code `0xC000003E` (`STATUS_DATA_ERROR`). I am struggling to understand what is wrong with this key component that is causing the issue OR there is something else that I am overlooking here.

Please see the complete code below:
function: DES_Dec1 works fine but DES_Dec2 returns error.
the only difference between DES_Dec1 and DES_Dec2 is that 
KEY_DES is "0x40, 0x64, 0xDA, 0xD9, 0x64, 0x0D, 0xA1, 0x1A" in DES_Dec1 
and "0xCB, 0x54, 0xF4, 0xE5, 0xF1, 0x94, 0x7C, 0xAD" in DES_Dec2.

```
        #include <windows.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <bcrypt.h>
        #pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt.lib")

        #include <iostream>
        #include<string>
        #include<sstream>
        #include<array>

        namespace  CryptoAPI
        {

        #define NT_SUCCESS(Status)          (((NTSTATUS)(Status)) >= 0)

        #define STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL         ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000001L)

        #define DATA_TO_ENCRYPT  "Test Data"

            void PrintBytes(
                IN BYTE     *pbPrintData,
                IN DWORD    cbDataLen)
            {
                DWORD dwCount = 0;

                for (dwCount = 0; dwCount < cbDataLen; dwCount++)
                {
                    printf("0x%02x, ", pbPrintData[dwCount]);

                    if (0 == (dwCount + 1) % 10) putchar('\n');
                }

            }

            void DES_Enc()
            {
                BYTE INPUTDATA_DES[] =
                {
                    0xF0, 0xA0, 0xC0, 0x19, 0xA0, 0x85, 0xF0, 0x01
                };

                BYTE KEY_DES[] =
                {
                    0x40, 0x64, 0xDA, 0xD9, 0x64, 0x0D, 0xA1, 0x1A//, 0xCB, 0x54, 0xF4, 0xE5, 0xF1, 0x94, 0x7C, 0xAD
                };

                BYTE IV_DES[] =
                {
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
                };

                BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE       hDesAlg = NULL;
                BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE       hKey = NULL;
                NTSTATUS                status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
                DWORD                   cbOutput = 0,
                                        cbInput = 0,
                                        cbData = 0,
                                        cbKeyObject = 0,
                                        cbBlockLen = 0;
                PBYTE                   pbOutput = NULL,
                                        pbInput = NULL,
                                        pbKeyObject = NULL,
                                        pbIV = NULL;

                // Open an algorithm handle.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
                    &hDesAlg,
                    BCRYPT_DES_ALGORITHM,
                    NULL,
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

            // Calculate the size of the buffer to hold the KeyObject.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(
                    hDesAlg,
                    BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH,
                    (PBYTE)&cbKeyObject,
                    sizeof(DWORD),
                    &cbData,
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

            // Allocate the key object on the heap.
                pbKeyObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbKeyObject);
                if (NULL == pbKeyObject)
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }



// Calculate the block length for the IV.
                    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(
                        hDesAlg,
                        BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH,
                        (PBYTE)&cbBlockLen,
                        sizeof(DWORD),
                        &cbData,
                        0)))
                    {
                        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n", status);
                        goto Cleanup;
                    }

                    // Determine whether the cbBlockLen is not longer than the IV length.
                    if (cbBlockLen > sizeof(IV_DES))
                    {
                        wprintf(L"**** block length is longer than the provided IV length\n");
                        goto Cleanup;
                    }

                // Allocate a buffer for the IV. The buffer is consumed during the 
                // encrypt/decrypt process.
                    pbIV = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbBlockLen);
                    if (NULL == pbIV)
                    {
                        wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                        goto Cleanup;
                    }

                    memcpy(pbIV, IV_DES, cbBlockLen);

                    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptSetProperty(
                        hDesAlg,
                        BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE,
                        (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC,
                        sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC),
                        0)))
                    {
                        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptSetProperty\n", status);
                        goto Cleanup;
                    }


                    // Generate the key from supplied input key bytes.
                    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(
                        hDesAlg,
                        &hKey,
                        pbKeyObject,
                        cbKeyObject,
                        (PBYTE)KEY_DES,
                        sizeof(KEY_DES),
                        0)))
                    {
                        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey\n", status);
                        goto Cleanup;
                    }

                cbInput = sizeof(INPUTDATA_DES);
                pbInput = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbInput);
                if (NULL == pbInput)
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                memcpy(pbInput, INPUTDATA_DES, sizeof(INPUTDATA_DES));

            //
            // Get the output buffer size.
            //
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptEncrypt(
                    hKey,
                    pbInput,
                    cbInput,
                    NULL,
                    pbIV,
                    cbBlockLen,
                    NULL,
                    0,
                    &cbOutput,
                    BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptEncrypt\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                pbOutput = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbOutput);
                if (NULL == pbOutput)
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Use the key to encrypt the plaintext buffer.
                // For block sized messages, block padding will add an extra block.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptEncrypt(
                    hKey,
                    pbInput,
                    cbInput,
                    NULL,
                    pbIV,
                    cbBlockLen,
                    pbOutput,
                    cbOutput,
                    &cbData,
                    BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptEncrypt\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Destroy the key and reimport from saved BLOB.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDestroyKey(hKey)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptDestroyKey\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }
                hKey = 0;

                if (pbInput)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbInput);
                }

                pbInput = NULL;

            Cleanup:

                if (hDesAlg)
                {
                    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hDesAlg, 0);
                }

                if (hKey)
                {
                    BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);
                }

                if (pbOutput)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbOutput);
                }

                if (pbInput)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbInput);
                }

                if (pbKeyObject)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbKeyObject);
                }

                if (pbIV)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbIV);
                }


            void DES_Dec1()
            {
                BYTE INPUTDATA_DES[] =
                {
                    0xc7, 0x85, 0x34, 0x3d, 0xef, 0x9b, 0xa2, 0x26, 0xed, 0xb7, 0x57, 0xb1, 0x60, 0x73, 0xd1, 0xee
                };


                BYTE KEY_DES[] =
                {
                    0x40, 0x64, 0xDA, 0xD9, 0x64, 0x0D, 0xA1, 0x1A
                    //0xCB, 0x54, 0xF4, 0xE5, 0xF1, 0x94, 0x7C, 0xAD
                };

                BYTE IV_DES[] =
                {
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
                };

                BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE       hDesAlg = NULL;
                BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE       hKey = NULL;
                NTSTATUS                status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
                DWORD                   cbOutput = 0,
                                        cbInput = 0,
                                        cbData = 0,
                                        cbKeyObject = 0,
                                        cbBlockLen = 0;
                PBYTE                   pbOutput = NULL,
                                        pbInput = NULL,
                                        pbKeyObject = NULL,
                                        pbIV = NULL;

                // Open an algorithm handle.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
                    &hDesAlg,
                    BCRYPT_DES_ALGORITHM,
                    NULL,
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Calculate the size of the buffer to hold the KeyObject.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(
                    hDesAlg,
                    BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH,
                    (PBYTE)&cbKeyObject,
                    sizeof(DWORD),
                    &cbData,
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Allocate the key object on the heap.
                pbKeyObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbKeyObject);
                if (NULL == pbKeyObject)
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Calculate the block length for the IV.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(
                    hDesAlg,
                    BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH,
                    (PBYTE)&cbBlockLen,
                    sizeof(DWORD),
                    &cbData,
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Determine whether the cbBlockLen is not longer than the IV length.
                if (cbBlockLen > sizeof(IV_DES))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** block length is longer than the provided IV length\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Allocate a buffer for the IV. The buffer is consumed during the 
                // encrypt/decrypt process.
                pbIV = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbBlockLen);
                if (NULL == pbIV)
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                memcpy(pbIV, IV_DES, cbBlockLen);

                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptSetProperty(
                    hDesAlg,
                    BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE,
                    (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC,
                    sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC),
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptSetProperty\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }


                // Generate the key from supplied input key bytes.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(
                    hDesAlg,
                    &hKey,
                    pbKeyObject,
                    cbKeyObject,
                    (PBYTE)KEY_DES,
                    sizeof(KEY_DES),
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                cbInput = sizeof(INPUTDATA_DES);
                pbInput = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbInput);
                if (NULL == pbInput)
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                memcpy(pbInput, INPUTDATA_DES, sizeof(INPUTDATA_DES));

                //
                //
                // Get the output buffer size.
                //
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDecrypt(
                    hKey,
                    pbInput,
                    cbInput,
                    NULL,
                    pbIV,
                    cbBlockLen,
                    NULL,
                    0,
                    &cbOutput,
                    BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptDecrypt\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                cbOutput = 32;
                pbOutput = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbOutput);
                if (NULL == pbOutput)
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDecrypt(
                    hKey,
                    pbInput,
                    cbInput,
                    NULL,
                    pbIV,
                    cbBlockLen,
                    pbOutput,
                    cbOutput,
                    &cbOutput,
                    BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptDecrypt\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

            Cleanup:

                if (hDesAlg)
                {
                    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hDesAlg, 0);
                }

                if (hKey)
                {
                    BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);
                }

                if (pbOutput)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbOutput);
                }

                if (pbInput)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbInput);
                }

                if (pbKeyObject)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbKeyObject);
                }

                if (pbIV)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbIV);
                }
            }

            void DES_Dec2()
            {
                BYTE INPUTDATA_DES[] =
                {
                    0xc7, 0x85, 0x34, 0x3d, 0xef, 0x9b, 0xa2, 0x26, 0xed, 0xb7, 0x57, 0xb1, 0x60, 0x73, 0xd1, 0xee
                };

                BYTE KEY_DES[] =
                {
                    0xCB, 0x54, 0xF4, 0xE5, 0xF1, 0x94, 0x7C, 0xAD
                };

                BYTE IV_DES[] =
                {
                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
                };

                BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE       hDesAlg = NULL;
                BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE       hKey = NULL;
                NTSTATUS                status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
                DWORD                   cbOutput = 0,
                    cbInput = 0,
                    cbData = 0,
                    cbKeyObject = 0,
                    cbBlockLen = 0;
                PBYTE                   pbOutput = NULL,
                    pbInput = NULL,
                    pbKeyObject = NULL,
                    pbIV = NULL;

                // Open an algorithm handle.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
                    &hDesAlg,
                    BCRYPT_DES_ALGORITHM,
                    NULL,
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Calculate the size of the buffer to hold the KeyObject.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(
                    hDesAlg,
                    BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH,
                    (PBYTE)&cbKeyObject,
                    sizeof(DWORD),
                    &cbData,
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Allocate the key object on the heap.
                pbKeyObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbKeyObject);
                if (NULL == pbKeyObject)
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Calculate the block length for the IV.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(
                    hDesAlg,
                    BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH,
                    (PBYTE)&cbBlockLen,
                    sizeof(DWORD),
                    &cbData,
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Determine whether the cbBlockLen is not longer than the IV length.
                if (cbBlockLen > sizeof(IV_DES))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** block length is longer than the provided IV length\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                // Allocate a buffer for the IV. The buffer is consumed during the 
                // encrypt/decrypt process.
                pbIV = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbBlockLen);
                if (NULL == pbIV)
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                memcpy(pbIV, IV_DES, cbBlockLen);

                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptSetProperty(
                    hDesAlg,
                    BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE,
                    (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC,
                    sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC),
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptSetProperty\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }


                // Generate the key from supplied input key bytes.
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(
                    hDesAlg,
                    &hKey,
                    pbKeyObject,
                    cbKeyObject,
                    (PBYTE)KEY_DES,
                    sizeof(KEY_DES),
                    0)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                cbInput = sizeof(INPUTDATA_DES);
                pbInput = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbInput);
                if (NULL == pbInput)
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                memcpy(pbInput, INPUTDATA_DES, sizeof(INPUTDATA_DES));

                //
                //
                // Get the output buffer size.
                //
                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDecrypt(
                    hKey,
                    pbInput,
                    cbInput,
                    NULL,
                    pbIV,
                    cbBlockLen,
                    NULL,
                    0,
                    &cbOutput,
                    BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptDecrypt\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                cbOutput = 32;
                pbOutput = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbOutput);
                if (NULL == pbOutput)
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDecrypt(
                    hKey,
                    pbInput,
                    cbInput,
                    NULL,
                    pbIV,
                    cbBlockLen,
                    pbOutput,
                    cbOutput,
                    &cbOutput,
                    BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptDecrypt\n", status);
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

            Cleanup:

                if (hDesAlg)
                {
                    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hDesAlg, 0);
                }

                if (hKey)
                {
                    BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);
                }

                if (pbOutput)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbOutput);
                }

                if (pbInput)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbInput);
                }

                if (pbKeyObject)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbKeyObject);
                }

                if (pbIV)
                {
                    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbIV);
                }

            }

            void wmain()
            {
                DES_Enc();
                DES_Dec1();
                DES_Dec2();
            }
        }
            }
```

Comment: Please include the code causing the issue so we can see if there is anything obvious that might be contributing to the issue.

Comment: Add the *full* code, with actual parameters/variables.

Comment: Hi @Mgetz, Just added the complete code. Thanks

Comment: Hi @MichaelChourdakis,  Just added the complete code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
BYTE INPUTDATA_DES[] =
{
    0xc7, 0x85, 0x34, 0x3d, 0xef, 0x9b, 0xa2, 0x26, 0xed, 0xb7, 0x57, 0xb1, 0x60, 0x73, 0xd1, 0xee
};
```

Above data is encrypted using `{0x40, 0x64, 0xDA, 0xD9, 0x64, 0x0D, 0xA1, 0x1A}` that's why you can't decryption it using `{0xCB, 0x54, 0xF4, 0xE5, 0xF1, 0x94, 0x7C, 0xAD}`.

The following data is the result encrypted with `{0xCB, 0x54, 0xF4, 0xE5, 0xF1, 0x94, 0x7C, 0xAD}`:

```
{0xb3, 0x33, 0x12, 0x44, 0xc5, 0x1e, 0x1e, 0xe0, 0x95, 0xb1, 0xd1, 0x2a, 0x7b, 0x61, 0x5f, 0x2a}
```

Comment: Thanks @RitaHan, however I am not very convinced that a single DES decryption cannot work on encrypted data (of Single DES Enc of another key).
For decryption, the input is just a 16 byte block that needs be decrypted by another key block, it can output any random data but decryption function itself shouldn't fail. Just to clarify, I am not expecting the decryption() would output value same as PlainText used for enc() with key(4064..). Actually 3DES encryption works on principle of data being encrypted-decrypted-encrypted by 2/3 different 8-byte key blocks. Am i missing something?

Comment: I believe Single DES encryption/decryption should work as long as:
- any input block of 8/16 bytes.
- any key block 8-byte long.

it should generate the output based on provided input. 
My intention is to perform Triple-DES encryption by performing encryption-decryption-encryption by 3-different 8 byte key components:K1, K2 and K3 such as:
Final output =  Enc(K3,Dec(K2, Enc(K1,data))).

However so far I am not able to achieve this. I have also tried option 'BCRYPT_3DES_ALGORITHM' but this also seem not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason for this behavior. This is caused by the flag `BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING`.

If you are trying to decrypt a buffer that was not encrypted with this flag (or, equivalently, was not encrypted with the same padding algorithm) the API will fail with this obscure status.

Comment: I tried this but didnt help. BcryptDecrypt was successful , returned 0 , but the data is not decrypted correctly